# Multiple messages makes socket.io app slower

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm building a game using React.js and node.js using socket.io.

The purpose of the game is to guess the opponent's character by asking questions using a chat.

I noticed that when posting messages, the more messages the longer they take to appear, ie the first 5 appear almost instantly but every single new message take a bit longer and I get timed out around the 11th/12th messages.

The issue appears even in localhost.

[Here's some debug log for the first messages (fast)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWTj4.png)

[Here's some debug log for the last messages(slow)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAyXM.png)

As stated here ([Socket IO chat example is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009835/socket-io-chat-example-is-slow)), I tried doing, but it didn't work:

```html
var io = require('socket.io')(http, { wsEngine: 'ws' });
```

my githubs repos:
server: https://github.com/tboittin/qsie_server

client: https://github.com/tboittin/qsie_client

You can access the game here: https://qsie-client.vercel.app/
It's in french so:

- on 1st screen -> bottom left button
- on 2nd screen -> blue button
- on 3rd screen -> type a username in the field and click the blue button on screen and in the modal
- on 4th screen -> Click on the blue button on screen and blue button in the modal
- on 5th screen -> Click on the blue button
- on 6th screen -> the chatbox is on the right

If you want to play the game, just open another tab, repeat until 4th screen and click on the big letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as you need a cleanup function for the useEffect or else with each message sent the rendering will increase and the whole app gets slow. If you use message as your dependency array all the messages wont load and messages will keep on getting replaced with next message.

```html
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("message", (message) => {
      setMessages([...messages, message]);
    });
    return()=>{
    socket.off('message')
    }
  }, [messages]);
```

Comment: Yeah thanks bro for correcting me, I used this in the end but forgot about this question, I'll edit it

Answer (score -1):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("message", (message) => {
      setMessages([...messages, message]);
    });
    return()=>{
    socket.off('message')
    }
  }, [socket]);
```

Comment: You copied the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68250688/) but changed the watchlist to `socket` instead of `messages`. Why?

Comment: useEffect callback will run every time when messages state is changed  setMessages([...messages, message]) is called inside the callback itself it may create loop

Comment: I don't think so. 1) Event listener added, `messages` changes when socket gets a new message. 2) Dependency triggers, causing the event listener to clean up. 3) Event listener is re-added. No loops here. While I'm not sure at first glance why it has to be in a `useEffect` at all, changing `messages` to `socket` doesn't make much sense in this context.